# Advertised "12V-Switch" needs at least 12V to function?

Tags: switches

Why hello there,

in short, I am working on an Arduino-project and I want to use following push-switches:
([https://www.amazon.com/Black-Button-Switch-Durable-Professional/dp/B01CFYWBQE/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1472992998&sr=8-4&keywords=12V+push+button+SPST+10pcs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01CFYWBQE))

The only problem is that I'm not sure if they work without a minimum of 12V, since they're advertised to work with devices that can output 12V, such as cars and boats.

Is it only an advertisment-trick to reconfirm car and boat-owners that these switches will indeed work with their product as well, or do they really work just with 12V or above?
I tried contacting the seller, but it was futile. Thanks in advance!

Comment: From appearances of ad and price, it may be unreliable for low current operation. (ie not gold plated for use <2A) If so add an electrolytic cap across contacts for wetting current.

Comment: Why's that exactly?

Comment: This looks like a good boat horn switch. Contacts rated for logic currents need to be gold plated or have induced "wetting " current to burn off contact oxide. Thus low ESR electrolytic cap, like tantalum or alum. will have short surge current on contact closure to "wet" or burn off insulating oxide that builds up in air on silver alloy contacts. Relays and switches rated for <2A all have gold plating. These probably don't.

Comment: This is an example of "buyer beware" with unspec'd unsupported possible rejected lot parts on EBay. But in some cases ok, it's cheap.  COntacts may be polarized with dim LED +R inside for indicating power is ON.

Comment: So, in other words, anything rated for less than 2A is (usually) good to go out of the box for 5V, 40mA. Well then, shouldn't use Amazon for the physical components at least...

Comment: I once used P&B power relays with extra signal contacts for my use in TTL logic sensing of remote operation. Failure rate was high until I added pullup R and 22uF tantalum across contacts. Typical wetting specs are 10% of rated current for non gold plated contacts.

Comment: You should post this question to the Amazon's supplier.  EE.SE isn't his volunteer application support.

Comment: Using components without a proper datasheet is always a gamble, and the only way to find out if those switches will work is to try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no illumination then a switch is a switch is a switch. The voltage rating is the *maximum* voltage that it is designed to work with.

If there is illumination then the illumination will be rated to work at the stated voltage, and lower voltages will either not illuminate or illuminate only dimly. The switch functionality will still function though since that is just pieces of metal that touch each other.

Comment: Alright, wicked! Thanks a bunch for clarifying this, I was wondering about that for a while now.